# Scoring with PROC PLM with model created with PROC GLM

Tags: sas

I've created a model using PROC GLM with only 150 nonparametric observations and 5 dependent variables, where some independent variables are categorical and some are continuous.

The output came out fine but when I tried to score it to a new dataset using PROC PLM, I am observing some null values in the predicted column.

For one dependent variable, I figured out that it was one class of the categorical variable that was causing the problem (i.e. when dataset contains an observation where Variable X = 10, predicted value for that observation comes out as ".").

When I delete any observations from the new dataset where i.e. Variable X = 10,  all predicted values score up as I expected them to. I don't understand why this maybe happening.

For the other 4 dependent variables, I cannot find the cause of null predicted values.

Is there something I should be doing with the data/model/score statement?

Thank you.

Comment: For the categorical variables check that the level of the categorical variable was in the initial dataset. If it was not, the model will not be able to account for the value. I wouldn't expect to see any issues with continuous variables. I don't think this is a valid SO question as it doesn't really related to a programming question.

Comment: @Reeza Questions about stats are divided as such:  "How do I do X" is mostly [stats.se] while "How do I do X in SAS" is mostly here, with some wiggle room in both cases.  It's unclear exactly whether this is a lack of understanding of SAS or of the underlying statistics, but since it's "in SAS" it is allowed here.

Comment: I would say that this question would be a much better question, and possibly be reasonably answerable, if it had example data that generated the problem in the post.

Comment: @Joe normally I agree but this isn't really a programming question at all, but how to debug thats too vague.

Comment: It is definitely too vague, that I fully agree with, without example data and code.